# ArrayAdapter goes beyond bounds

Tags: android

I have an `ArrayAdapter` with `ArrayList` filled. Each time I click on any of its item I re-fill the `ArrayList` and send `notifyOnDataSetChange()` to the `adapter`. But for unknown for me reason it goes out of `ArrayList` bounds in it's `getView()` method where it populates its items. I don't understand why this happens. Can you guys explain the theory of `getView()` invokation so I understand why this going on. Thanks in advance!

Here it is:

```
class MAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    public MAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, List<String> objects) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = convertView;
    if (v == null) {
        LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = vi.inflate(R.layout.file_explorer_row, null);
    } else {

    }

        String txt = itemsList.get(position); // Out of bounds happens here
        if (!txt.equals("")) {
            TextView tt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.file_explorer_tv_filename);
            tt.setText(txt);
        }

    return v;
}
```

`itemsList` is declared in Outer Class.

Comment: here  itemsList where you declared..

Comment: Rather than extending Adapter class by ArrayAdapter,extend it by BaseAdapter.implement four methods and include arrayList.size() in  getCount() function and return position in remaining two itemid functions

Comment: R u filling the whole ArrayList again, or just appending few things to the list ??

Comment: I'm filling the whole ArrayList again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though i am not getting a clear view of what you are asking..i am assuming that , you are refilling the entire ArrayAdapter again....

So try this.........

**Use removeView() on ListView before setting the adapter to it...**

Eg:

```
ListView.removeView(); 
ListView.setAdapter(yourAdapter);
```

Comment: it works, thanks! But I'm using `ListView.removeAllViewsInLayout();`. Do you know the answer why this happens?

Comment: Actually when you start the app for the first time, the ListView is empty, then you add Data in it (Actually its Views with data internally)... When you try to do it the Second time, again WITHOUT RESTARTING THE APP, it gets appended to the ListView which is already filled, now when you try to access it.. ArrayAdapter gets out of bound, actually its the ArrayList out of bound

Answer (score 1):

change like this

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {         
        View view = convertView;
        if (view == null) 
        {              
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);          
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.file_explorer_row, parent, false);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

`String txt = itemsList.get(position);`
 `itemsList.get(position)` returns a Integer Value and that you are try to store in a String..this might be the reason.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
class MAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    List<String> objects;
    Context context;
    public MAdapter(Context context,List<String> objects) {
        super();
        this.context=context;
        this.objects=objects;
    }



    public int getCount() {
        return objects.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = convertView;
    Holder holder;
    LayoutInflater vi;
    if (v == null) {
        holder=new Holder();
        vi = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = vi.inflate(R.layout.file_explorer_row, null);
        holder.tt= (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.file_explorer_tv_filename);
        v.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (Holder) v.getTag();
    }
        String txt = objects.get(position); // Out of bounds happens here
        if (!txt.equals("")) {
            holder.tt.setText(txt);
        }

    return v;
}

static class Holder{
    TextView tt;
}
}
```